# Cycles Render - Baking texture without light influence

Tags: texture-baking

would like to ask the community about 1 single simple question. Was trying to find my own answers, but few that I have found, somehow, sent me to same solution that I was trying over and over, perhaps the Blender +2.7 has changed compared to the old answers and videos that I have found .. don't know, that is why i am here.

My question is:
- is it possible to bake texture/s in cycles render without any external light influence and the textures should be acceptable visible? (all are dark for me since I don't use external light).

I would like to know this because I don't wish to have any type of shadows over my texture when I port it to an engine and inside the engine I will give the light to it.
If there is a solution to this but might take to much text to write it down then either pm me or forward me to a good video/text.
If the question is not clear and needs more specification then let me know, I will try to reformulate it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, looks like after not quitting I have managed to find the solution.
I don't know if it is a work around for my problem or not, but it works, I did managed to add my file in the engine and has no problem, it is exactly as I was hopping to be.

Solution:
You will need to make emission instead of diffuse in the node that you will bake. Here it is a little bit more to talk how exactly I managed to bake it, but I don't wish to make lots of writings here. The solution was the above mentioned. You will need to bake from 1 object to another (by copying the original obj. with SHIFT+D) and for baking solution you will choice COMBINED (leave all the selected ones there).

I hope that I will manage to record all this in a short tutorial and link it here.. I will need to find myself a decent desktop recorder. 
Hope that my explanation was clear enough, if not then pm me and I will gladly explain it step by step.

Blender version that I have is 2.77

Simple node settings image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZpgA.jpg

Bake image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRPlY.jpg

Comment: It's not needed to duplicate objects just to bake texture; in Bake options uncheck *Selected To Active* and bake will work for 1 object only. Also usually for baking textures Emit or Diffuse with only Color pass enabled are used.